# how to sum each array if number of an array element is 10 quickly in python3?

Tags: python, arrays

```
a_h= np.array([1,2,4,6])
b_h=np.array([7,12,19,11,17,18,1,13,17,2])
c_h=np.array([20,5,4,8,14,10,8,13])
d_h=np.array([18,20,16,1,20,18,20,17,15,9])
e_h=np.array([20,20,17,12,20,14,9,5,16,9])
f_h=np.array([17,5,16,3,4,6,16])
```

I got so many array. I need to sum each array if the len(array)=10, and change array name by replace '_h'  with '_sum'. Here are the code I try to， but it failed.

```
for i in range(len(dir())):
    if len(eval(dir()[i]))==10:
        dir()[i]=np.zeros(10)+np.nan
        newdata=np.sum()
        dir()[i].replace('_h','_sum') = newdata
```

Here are the result I want:

```
b_sum= 117
d_sum = 154
...
```

Many thanks for your kindness to help

Comment: Using `eval` is not a wise option. How are you iterating through the arrays? Are they in a list?

Comment: You should be using a real data structure. If the name `c_h` and `c_sum` are significant, those strings should be keys in a dictionary or the values should be in different lists indicating whether the are `_h` values or `_sum` values. Having significant information encoded in variable names is not scalable or maintainable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to solve this problem using exec and globals().

```
import numpy as np

a_h= np.array([1,2,4,6])
b_h=np.array([7,12,19,11,17,18,1,13,17,2])
c_h=np.array([20,5,4,8,14,10,8,13])
d_h=np.array([18,20,16,1,20,18,20,17,15,9])
e_h=np.array([20,20,17,12,20,14,9,5,16,9])
f_h=np.array([17,5,16,3,4,6,16])
##I got so many array.
# I need to sum each array if the len(array)=10, and change array name by replace '_h' with '_sum'.

vars = [var for var in globals() if var.endswith("_h")]
for var in vars:
    if len(eval(var)) == 10:
        varname_new = var.replace("_h","_sum")
        value_new = sum(eval(var))
        exec('{} =  {}'.format(varname_new,value_new))
        del globals()[var]
```

Any questions, let me know.